# Technicality on the definition of contractible space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a fairly simple problem with understanding the definition of contractible spaces, but just can't solve it.

Clearly, the unit disk $D^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an example of a contractible space, while $S^1$ is not. This means that the identity map in $D^2$ is homotopic to a constant map, which doesn't happen in $S^1$. The constant map, however, is always continuous, so I don't see how there wouldn't exist a homotopy $H: I\times S^1\rightarrow \{ p\} $ between the identity and the constant map. Why isn't it the case, and why is it possible for $D^2$?

Why, for example, is the function $H: I\times S^1\rightarrow \{ p\} $ that maps $x\in S^1$ to $p$ by "walking $x$ in the circle until it gets to $p$" not a homotopy?

Comment: How does the antipode of $p$ decide which way to walk?  What happens to a neighborhood of the antiipode?  Does being in a neighborhood of the antipode force points to follow a path different than the one prescribed by the map?

Comment: Well, if we decide all points are walking , say, clockwise, I still don't see why the antipode of p would walk on a different direction.

Comment: But if everyone goes clockwise, how does someone who's right next to $p$, but on the wrong side of it, get to $p$ ?

Comment: Well, it'd still do all the path towards p; where's the contradiction?

Comment: @TPace : Actually write down the map that you say works.  (It's feasible to explicitly write these maps for $S^1$.)  You are successfully arguing that until you see the map, you won't see the failure.

Comment: Now that I worked the problem more directly I understood it; thank you both!

Comment: You should edit your question. (1) You say "the constant map". There are many constent maps, one for each $p \in S^1$. (2) The homotopy $H$ is a map $H : S^1 \times I \to S^1$ such that $H(x,0) = x$ and $H(x,1) = p$ for some $p \in S^1$,

Comment: $D^2$ is contratible because $H : D^2 \times I \to D^2, H(x,t) =t x$, is a homotopy from the identity map to a constant map. That $S^1$ is not contractible is a non-trivial theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, although I shall keep the question as it was once the mistakes I made were the reasons for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, for $S^1$, the identity cannot be deformed to a constant without leaving $S^1$.  The homotopy, if it exists, gives a deformation of the space to a point.  But there's a hole in $S^1$.  Not the case for $D^2$.

Look at the definition of homotopy to see why:  $H:S^1\times I\to S^1$.  You have to be able to stay within the space while deforming it.  There's no way to pull $S^1$ apart and deform it to a point in $S^1$ continuously.

Comment: Why would we need to leave $S^1$? The example I gave in last paragraph doesn't leave the circle, but I can't see why it is not a homotopy.

Comment: There's no way to do that continuously.  You would have to break, cut, or separate the circle at some point to do it.

Comment: Intuitively I can see you'd need to cut/separate the circle, but because the constant map is always continuous I can't see this happening in the theory itself.

Comment: The constant map is continuous, and so is the identity.  But there's no way to continuously get from one to the other.

Comment: Oh, I see what I got wrong: as you wrote, the range is S^1, not {p}! Thank you!